# How to flash memory when there is no sector information?

Tags: flash, transmitter, software, nxp, flash-memories

Currently, I am trying to flash WCT1013A. As I see in the datasheet there is no sector information. If I do not know about the sector information how am I going to flash the memory?

Comment: Might be best you contact NXP.

Comment: Datasheet ? This https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/WCT101XV10AUG.pdf ?

Comment: Yes and also all of the other files here https://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/wireless-power/15-watt-wireless-charging-transmitter-ics-for-automotive-applications:MWCT1x1xA?#design-resources